# I need to Populate more then one Combo box from the same database table

Tags: excel, database, vba, ado

I Need to populate many combo boxes with the same table. In the code at the line with `Me.cobobox3` I need to add many other combo boxes but have no idea how.

```
'Load Employee Number in List Box
Dim cn1 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rt1 As New ADODB.Recordset

'Opening a connection to the database
dbPath = Sheets("Info").Range("a3").Value
cn1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

'Getting Data from database
rt1.Open "SELECT * FROM EmployeeTypes", cn1, adOpenStatic
rt1.MoveFirst

'Setting where to show the Employee Record
With Me.ComboBox3
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rt1![EmpType]
        rt1.MoveNext
    Loop Until rt1.EOF
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Array of ComboBoxes:

```
Dim Combos(1) as ComboBox 'replace 1 with the number of your comboboxes
Set Combos(0) = yourFirstComboBox
Set Combos(1) = yourSecondComboBox
' ...

For Each cb in Combos
    With cb
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rt1![EmpType]
            rt1.MoveNext
        Loop Until rt1.EOF
    End With
Next cb
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help . I now get a Type mismatch error on the Next combox

Comment: I forgot that VBA does not distinguish non-capital and capital letters. See my edit :)

Comment: Ok I changed everything and it still gives me the mismatch type error on the Next cb